# listbox sorting issue when in ownerdrawfixed mode

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listbox

I have a listbox with the sorted property set to true. When the drawmode is set to normal, it sorts as expected, in alphabetical order. But, when I have the drawmode set to ownerdrawfixed so that I can change the color of certain items, then the sorted order is quite different. It is not as if the sorted property is set to false (which would list the items in the order added to the list), but I have not figured out what order it is using. The item class used to change the color only has 2 properties: the text (as string), and the color... with the text being the first property. Each time I run the program, the list is the same, so it's not random. But it definitely is not alphabetical. I have no code to post since I set the sorted property at design time, there's nothing that would change this in the code.

I am including a screen shot with 4 Listboxes, which should show what is happening.
[Sorting Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yif1z.jpg)

I have searched for listbox sorting issues, to which only 2 posts show, neither of which addresses this issue.

Comment: Data samples would be in order....if the item text contains numerals they may not sort as you expect...or it could be what you are doing in the DrawItem method since it is ownerDraw.  And we do not need or like language tags in the title - it is just noise and that is what the tags are for

Comment: The data is a movie title list, so some may contain numbers, but most would not. Originally I was using the drawmode = normal... which worked great for putting the titles in alphabetical order. But, there are other criteria which I wanted to change the color of certain items, so I had to change it to ownerdrawfixed. But now the order is nothing near alphabetical, nor is it in anyway the order the titles were added to the list (sorted = false).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around, but I do not believe this should be necessary, and it is extra processing and overhead that I feel there should not need to be. 
I have tried feeding the data into a sorted, drawmode normal, non-visible listbox, and then read this 1 item at a time and feed it into a non-sorted, drawmode ownerdrawfixed listbox so that I can change the color of some items. While this does work, it could eventually slow the program down if there are very many items to be read. And, I have figured out what order it is putting them in if I use a sorted ownerdrawfixed box to begin with. it is putting the first 2 items at the bottom of the list, then alternates top-bottom... so the order would be something like this....  3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1. I saw this when I first tried reading the sorted normal list and feeding it into the sorted ownerdrawfixed list to see where it was putting things in regards to order entered.